Configure AppLocker on AWS AppStream ImageBuilder
I have AWS AppStream 2.0 ImageBuilder.
Need to have ability to lock applications running there via AppLocker.
I follow this official guide to setup AppLocker.
To configure AppLocker rules I use this guide. And adding 3 executable rules

And after that I am not able to connect. Looks like this rules block myself from connecting.
Could you please advise what is the reason and how to deal with it?
If it is a wrong place for adding such question, please, suggest the correct site.
